# Translate Grammar to plain english

Tags: context-free-grammar

```
G ::= S
S ::= A M
A ::= a E | b A A
M ::= S | ϵ
E ::= a B | b A | ϵ
B ::= b E | a B B
```

where a and b are terminals

So I tried to do a derivation for this but I realized there's no point where you're left with just terminal variables? How do describe the grammar if it continuously goes in loops?

Comment: It can terminate. Here’s a terminating derivation: $$G\Rightarrow S\Rightarrow AM\Rightarrow aEM\Rightarrow aM\Rightarrow a$$ I used the productions $M\to\epsilon$ and $E\to\epsilon$ to get rid of the non-terminals. If it truly didn’t terminate, it would simply generate the empty language.

Comment: Can you just completely delete the M because it can map to ϵ??

Comment: Yes; that’s what it means to have a production $M\to\epsilon$. You replace $M$ by the empty string, which effectively simply erases $M$.

Comment: okay thanks!  that answered my question, our professor didn't really explain what the ϵ term did.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: one more question actually. If you were to do
G => S
    => AM
    => bAAM

you would end up with a b in the final result. Does that change what the grammar is doing?

Comment: I didn’t actually try to work out what language the grammar generates: I just saw that it does generate a non-empty language. It certainly generates both words beginning with $a$ and words beginning with $b$, but without careful analysis I can’t tell you more than that. I have to run some errands and will be away from the computer for several hours, but I can take a look at it later this evening if you like.

Comment: If i figure it out before then I'll leave a comment but other wise that would be great! thanks!